# If I own Beat Saber on PC, do I need to buy the game again to play the standalone Quest 2 version?

Tags: beat-saber, meta-quest-2

I have Beat Saber on my PC, but I want to play on a Quest 2. I usually use Oculus Link/Air Link to stream the game from my PC, but I want to play on my Quest 2 standalone.

Is is possible to get the standalone Quest 2 version if I already own the game on PC, or do I have to purchase Beat Saber again?

Comment: depending on how long you played the PC version, you could request a refund in order to buy it on the oculus store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The base version of Beat Saber does not support cross-buy. You will need to buy the game again if you want to play the standalone version on the Oculus Quest.

However, any DLC song packs bought through the Oculus Store will be available on the Quest via cross-buy.

> We decided not to do cross-buy for the base game because Quest is a new platform and porting the game took a significant amount of time.  All players who purchased Beat Saber Music Packs through Oculus Store will have all their packs available as a cross-buy.
>
> [@BeatSaber on Twitter](https://twitter.com/beatsaber/status/1202161100692819968) - Dec 4, 2019